# How can I reset a component to it's initial state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem: I have moved the markup/code of a modal to a separate component in react because the file was getting rather long and I might want to use it somewhere else.

I got it so that I can open it and close it, however if I want to reopen it it does not work. I suspect it is because I set a flag to show it to `false` when I click close, but I cannot reset it so it reopens.

My code is as follows

**In the main component**

```js
 const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);
...
<button
onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
type="button"
claseName="infobutton"
>
<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
</button>
...

 <InfoModal show={showModal} />
```

**In the InfoModal component**

```js
  const [ShowModal, setShowModal] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      {show && ShowModal ? (
...
<button
 className="closeButton"
 onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
 >
 <span className="closeButton">
                      ×
 </span>
 </button>
...
 </>
  );
```

What have I done wrong here and should there be a better way of doing this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the duplicate state from InfoModal, and instead pass your `setShowModal` from the Main component as a prop to InfoModal, e.g. `<InfoModal show={showModal} onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} />`

```
// Main Component
const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);
...
<button
  onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
  type="button"
  claseName="infobutton"
>
  <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
</button>
...

<InfoModal show={showModal} onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} />


// InfoModal Component
return (
  <>
    {show ? (
      ...
      <button
       className="closeButton"
       onClick={onClose}
       >
       <span className="closeButton">
                            ×
       </span>
       </button>
      ...
    )}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your second component in this way it should work. In your component you never set your state to true again and it never opens the modal

```
 const [ShowModal, setShowModal] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => { 
            setShowModal(show)    
      }, [props]); 
     
      return (
        <>
          {show ? (
    ...
    <button
     className="closeButton"
     onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
     >
     <span className="closeButton">
                          ×
     </span>
     </button>
    ...
     </>
      );
```